# Can I create my own God?

Tags: gods, worship, bhakti

I would like to know if it is possible to create my own God, and if so, will worshiping that god have the same value as worshiping others?

Comment: If you are well read in the Shastras, Hindu philosophy, Hindu ethics, and have contributed atleast 20-30 years studying the original Shastras in Sanskrit along with their major interpretations by the various schools, and respected among spiritual circles as a being possessing immense spiritual strength/ character, then yes. But, if you would have done all this, you wouldn't be asking this question here. So, in short, no you can't.

Comment: Its unclear unless you state, What do you mean by creating god? In short you might end up worship something pre existing or something that's just some random stuff or it might end up being a new religious movement.

Comment: We all create our own vision of God already. Every person's interpretation of the Godhead is different.

Comment: Yes you can. All religions are most likely manmade so you can create your own god.

Comment: @Wikash_ Indeed, you can. But it may not have any significance. People create dolls made of various materials (quite popular in vodoo circles, I hear) and play with them. No one is stopping you. But, I assumed if you wanted to say, 'create a god' then you wanted something meaningful, which impacts your life and the life of others around you positively. For this, you have to understand the science of worship in Hinduism. (1/2)

Comment: As I see from your profile, you are not from India, and perhaps not too familiar with the Hindu system of bhakti. Hinduism is altogether different from Abrahamic religions. Don't go only by the mythology. We had philosophers, who first found a sound basis of the science of worship. Using these principles, to take the concepts to the common man, perhaps, the mythologies were written by the rishis. Along with the mythologies, the philosophy was taken to the common man in the form of worship, which was easy to understand and repeat as a ritual. (2/2)

Comment: @IamThat I was raised in a hindu family and attained a lot temple visits and puja's so yes I am familiar. It is not clear whether the hindu gods or other truly have an impact. Currently, a flying spagettimonster might do the same as one of the deva's/devis.

Comment: @Wikash_ Not quite. Your superheroes like thor and captain america can't become devatas. The devatas have a solid tradition associated with them, a system of philosophy, associated mythologies based on the principles of the philosophy, which expound on their characteristics, which goes along with the devata.The tradition is upheld by serious spiritual aspirants who undergo hardships, and live a life of discipline, also called the guru-shishya parampara. Some paramparas have been going on for over than 1500 years, without dilution. They still continue. For example: Vaishnavas, Saktas, Shaivites

Comment: @Iamthat actually they can. In the mcu there are many philosophies and rules which are similar to a religion. Also, to this day people actually pray to Thor.

Answer (score -3):

Of course you can. The power of God lies in the faith of his devotee. How did so many gods come to exist in Hinduism. Many people do not have the need to create one. They choose one among the existing Gods.

```
ये यथा मां प्रपद्यन्ते तांस्तथैव भजाम्यहम्।
मम वर्त्मानुवर्तन्ते मनुष्याः पार्थ सर्वशः।।4.11।।
```

> Howsoever men try to worship Me, so do I welcome them. By whatever path they travel, it leads to Me at last

```
यो यो यां यां तनुं भक्तः श्रद्धयार्चितुमिच्छति।

तस्य तस्याचलां श्रद्धां तामेव विदधाम्यहम्।।7.21।।
```

> Whichever form any devotee wants to worship, in that very form do I make his faith steadfast.

In the end all that matters is Bhakti.

Comment: Your answer is a bit misleading. All that matters is Bhakti, indeed. But what is Bhakti? Some communities in name of devotion to god, murder people, cause inquisitions to be laid to punish heresy. Others blow themselves up by killing 'infidels'. That too can be said to be a form of perverse devotion, because in their view, god said so, and they are just following orders. But, is it Bhakti? I don't think so. Hence, the tradition and the attributes of god have to imbibe some basic qualities, which is found to be common across devatas in the Hinduism and is rooted in Hindu philosophical thought.

Comment: Appropriate quote by Srila Prabhupada in this context: “Religion without philosophy is sentiment, or sometimes fanaticism, while philosophy without religion is mental speculation.”